# ¿Cómo cambiar a negrita múltiples celdas con openpyxl.styles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, openpyxl

Importamos librería

```
from openpyxl.styles import Font
```

Creamos variable con celdas deseadas a cambiar la fuente a negrita

```
celdas_en_negrita = hoja_tres ['A1':'D1']
```

Aplicamos negrita

```
celdas_en_negrita.font = Font (bold = True)
```

Quiero cambiar a negrita las celdas `A1`, `B1`, `C1` y `D1`. Lo se hacer individualmente pero quería saber si existe una forma de hacerlo todo de golpe a las celdas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que generar un bucle para que recorra las celdas de la variable celdas_en_negrita. La variable negrita quita el .font ya que lo aplicas después:

```
celdas_en_negrita = hoja_tres["A1":"D1"]
fuente = Font(bold=True)


for row in celdas_en_negrita:
    for cell in row:
        cell.font = fuente
```